# Unknown Memory Leak with JSF 2.2 in Tomcat7

Tags: java, spring, jsf, memory-leaks, tomcat7

im actually facing a problem related to `memory leak` using `JSF2.2(Mojarra)` and `Tomcat7`, i will proceed to the details:

- The webpage contains many `datatables`, and have some options to select and export the data. Everything is stored in `session` (i readead all the good practices for JSF but in this case i been forced to use it)... unfortunately all the `datatables` are obligatory i know that this can consume too much memory, but i try to face it with `session-timeout` under 15 minutes. But even using it the memory grows to the max allowed of `Tomcat7` and never release the memory back to the server, even after hours.
- The webpage is actually working OK but with that big `memory leak`.
- What im trying to achive is to release the memory of the sessions that already been timed out to the server again.
- I have a little suspect that the problem is related with a `WARNING` that appears when the session is timed out and you try to do something in the app, on the logs print this:

> de nov. 16, 2017 2:55:46 PM
>   org.springframework.web.context.request.FacesRequestAttributes
>   registerDestructionCallback WARNING: **Could not register destruction**
>   **callback**
>   [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter@532ecd5b]
>   for attribute 'mainBean' because FacesRequestAttributes does not
>   support such callbacks
>
> de nov. 16, 2017 2:55:46 PM
>   org.springframework.web.context.request.FacesRequestAttributes
>   registerDestructionCallback WARNING: **Could not register destruction**
>   **callback**
>   [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter@5d5d8e9e]
>   for attribute 'otherBean' because FacesRequestAttributes does not
>   support such callbacks

- I have a main bean that contains other beans with `@Autowire` all the beans are scoped in session `@Scope=("session")`:

mainBean.java

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
@Qualifier("mainBean")
public class MainBean {
        @Autowired
        private OtherBeanClass otherBean;
        ...
}
```

otherBean.java

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
@Qualifier("otherBean")
public class OtherBean {
    ...
}
```

web.xml of WEB-INF (I readed that i can just add the listener `org.springframework.web.context.RequestContextListener` but it results as `ClassNotFoundException`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    version="2.5">
  <display-name>MainApp v3.3.0</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <session-config>
      <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
  </session-config>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyWebApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyWebApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>main-css</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/resources</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

web.xml of Tomcat (Because it is a very big file i put only what i think is related to my problem):

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

If you want me to show something more to get a better approach just ask.

Thanks for reading and I hope you can help me.

EDIT: After the kolossus's helping tip 
I managed to find the `RequestContextListener` inside my `org.springframework.web-3.0.6.release.jar` the correct declaration is:
(notice: `.context.request.RequestContextListener` and not `.context.RequestContextListener`)

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
```

Finally my `@PreDestroy` method is being called, but my server memory still on the max allowed.

Comment: So it works with jsf 2.1? Or with 2.3?

Comment: The lib of jsf is jsf 2.2 (Mojarra) javax.faces-2.2.9

Comment: And running java 1.8

Comment: Tried the latest mojarra? Latest spring? Latest 2.2 jsf namespaces?

Comment: The project im working on is a little old, it dosen't have maven, you know where i can find the libs you asking me to try? sorry for the inncovenience

Comment: I'd personally use Google to find that sort of info

Comment: The most effective way to troubleshoot a memory leak is to get a heap dump that will show you exactly what's clogging your heap. What specific error are you getting from tomcat? Perhaps what you have configured is too low? To be clear, [you must have the `RequestContextListener` registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077558/warn-could-not-register-destruction-callback) so you need to resolve your ClassNotFoundException.  Also try adding a `@PreDestroy` method to your session beans to confirm your session beans are indeed being destroyed.

Comment: kolossus i'll try your method thanks

Comment: Post edited with kolossus idea